# Use Async CTP VB with SqlDataAdapter for a Select statement and a DataSet

Tags: vb.net, sqldataadapter, async-ctp

I want to know how to use the ASYNC CTP to manage the querying of a SQL Database with a SQL Select statement and use a SQLDataAdapter to fill in a DataSet.  I have downloaded the VS2010 SP1 and the ASYNC CTP, I have also reviewed the videos on the MSDN site and the documentation included.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Can you elaborate more specific details?

Comment: I'm looking for an example of querying a database as a CTP task.  There don't seem to be any SQLDataAdapter methods that work with / for the an Async CTP client so I'm trying to figure out how to do it, and refresh the databindings when the task is complete.  I don't want the UI to be locked up while I'm waiting for a DB response.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I understand your question now.

You can't have SqlDataAdapter fill dataset asynchronously. SqlDataAdapter doesn't provide support for asynchronous event programming such as those in Windows Forms' PictureBox and SoundPlayer.

If you want to do async on SqlDataAdapter, you have to extend SqlDataAdapter to implement Completion and Cancellation event handling,  by yourself. You have to define completed event and async event args, by deriving from the AsyncCompletedEventArgs class.

For more information, visit: ["Walkthrough: Implementing a Component That Supports the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz33kx67%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on MSDN Library.